# Google Maps - Autocomplete & Directions API - trigger onchange() for dropdown list?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, driving-directions

I have Google Map and two inputs. Both of them use autocomplete, like this:

```
//first input autocomplete

var input1 = (document.getElementById('start'));
var autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1);

autocomplete1.bindTo('bounds', map);

//second input autocomplete

var input2 = (document.getElementById('end'));
var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2);

autocomplete2.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

After I fill both of these inputs I'm displaying the shortest way betweeen them using Directions API:

```
function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}
```

My inputs look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="start" onchange="calcRoute();" />
<input type="text" id="end" onchange="calcRoute();" />
```

**The Problem**:

Everything works perfectly fine if I type full addresses in these inputs for example:

Berlin, Germany & Hamburg, Germany (I guess that's because every letter typed triggers onchange()).

But when I type:

Berlin, Germany and then
Hamb > click on Hamburg from Google Autocomplete Dropdown List

It doesn't show Hamburg, it shows a town called Hamb.

Is there any way to fix it?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 2):

```
autocompleteTo = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('end')),
    {types: ['geocode']}
);
google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteTo, 'place_changed', function () {
    calcRoute();
});
```

Listening to the place_changed event is much more efficient then triggering a route recalculation on every change of the input field.

Comment: Not only it's much more efficient, it really is the only way to take advantage of Autocomplete. Otherwise, you'll be routing to/from what the use typed so far, not what Autocomplete suggested. And while you're at this, consider routing to/from the Place ID of places, as in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions