# calling Google Maps API for auto completing multiple location fields

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to call Google map api where it will auto complete address in location field. 
Now, I have 2 location field where I want to auto field it.

I have wrote following JavaScript code.

```
var options = {
componentRestrictions: { country: 'usa' }
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {

if (document.getElementById("address")) {

    var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('address'), options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = places.getPlace();
        var address = place.formatted_address;
        var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
        document.getElementById("Latitude").value = latitude;
        document.getElementById("Longitude").value = longitude;
    });
}

if (document.getElementById("addressModal")) {

    var placesModal = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('addressModal'), options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(placesModal, 'place_changed', function () {

        var placeModal = placesModal.getPlace();
        var latitudeModal = placeModal.geometry.location.lat();
        var longitudeModal = placeModal.geometry.location.lng();

        document.getElementById("Latitude").value = latitudeModal;
        document.getElementById("Longitude").value = longitudeModal;
    });
}});
```

It is auto completing for 1st location field (id = address) 
but it is not working for 2nd location field (id = addressModal) 
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: related question [Google Maps - Autocomplete & Directions API - trigger onchange() for dropdown list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690444/google-maps-autocomplete-directions-api-trigger-onchange-for-dropdown-li)

Comment: possibly similar question [Google Maps V3 autocomplete input jquery Mobile
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252188/google-maps-v3-autocomplete-input-jquery-mobile)

Comment: I get a javascript error with your code `options` is not defined, if [I fix that both fields work (with the error, neither works)](http://jsfiddle.net/3aLqbbz1/1/).

Comment: Hey. @geocodezip thanks for reply. I have edited question. I forgot to add options variable.

Comment: You are doing something you aren't telling us.  [Your code (still) works for me if I put it in an onload function](http://jsfiddle.net/3aLqbbz1/3/).  What javascript errors are you getting?  Are you including the places library (and the Google Maps Javascript API v3)?